# Number of Nearest 'True' in a matrix or list of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

In a 2D matrix, how do I find the number of neighbours that have the value I'm searching for? Neighbours are defined as 8-connected (vertically, horizontally and diagonally)

For instance, in the example below, for every element, X[i][j], in the matrix, I want to calculate how many of of it's neighbours have the value A

Sample Input:

```
matrix = [[A, B, A], 
          [B, A, A],
          [B, A, B]]
```

Sample Output:

```
solution   = [[1, 4, 2],
              [3, 4, 3],
              [2, 2, 3]]
```

Eg.

- `matrix[0][0]` has 1 neighbours with the value A --> `matrix[1][1]`
- `matrix[0][2]` has 2 neighbours with the value A --> `matrix[1][1]` and `matrix[1][2]`

Comment: can explain your question properly with example or output

Comment: It is poorly explained, I had to read 5 times that unique sentence.... But it is, in fact, an input / output.... You could have proposed an algorithm...

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not the best way to do it, but it's one that works:

```
import numpy as np

mas1 = np.array([[True, False,  True],
       [ False,  True,  True],
       [ False,  True,  False]])

mas_answer = np.ndarray(shape=mas1.shape)

for i in range(mas1.shape[0]):
    for j in range(mas1.shape[1]):
        close_elt = []
        if i >= 1:
            try:
                close_elt.append(mas1[i-1,j])
            except:
                pass
            try:
                close_elt.append(mas1[i-1,j+1])
            except:
                pass

        if j >= 1:
            try:
                close_elt.append(mas1[i+1,j-1])
            except:
                pass
            try:
                close_elt.append(mas1[i,j-1])
            except:
                pass

        if i >= 1 and j >= 1:
            try:
                close_elt.append(mas1[i-1,j-1])
            except:
                pass

        try:
            close_elt.append(mas1[i,j+1])
        except:
            pass

        try:
            close_elt.append(mas1[i+1,j])
        except:
            pass
        try:
            close_elt.append(mas1[i+1,j+1])
        except:
            pass

        mas_answer[i,j] = close_elt.count(True)


# Ouput:
mas_answer
Out[27]: 
array([[1., 4., 2.],
       [3., 4., 3.],
       [2., 2., 3.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably can try this Python approach:  *(just comment out the print statements)*
**# filename - my_neighbors.py**

```
from itertools import product

coordinates = list(product(range(3), range(3)))


matrix =  [['A', 'B', 'A'], 
           ['B', 'A', 'A'],
           ['B', 'A', 'B']]

# Number of Nearest 'True' in a matrix or list of list

         #   [[1, 4, 2],
         #    [3, 4, 3],
         #    [2, 2, 3]]


def neighbors(grid, r, c):
    vals = sum((row[c -(c>0): c+2]
                for row in grid[r -(r>0):r+2]), [])
    vals.remove(grid[r][c])      # rm itself.
    return list(vals)            # return all neighbors



new_matrix = [[0 for c in range(3)] for r in range(3)]
#print(new_matrix)

for r, c in coordinates:
    print(f' {r}{c} -> all neighbors: ')
    print(f' \t  {neighbors(matrix, r, c)} ')
    neighs = neighbors(matrix, r, c)
    summ   = neighs.count('A')
    print(f' \t \t summ: {summ} ')
    new_matrix[r][c] = summ


print(new_matrix)

# [[1, 4, 2], [3, 4, 3], [2, 2, 3]]
```